# Springer template svjour3 and unnumbered theorems

Tags: theorems, sv-classes, springer

I want to write an unnumbered theorem in a paper. I defined

`\spnewtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape}`

and expected to obtain

**Theorem** *Theorem text*

Instead, I obtained

***Theorem*** *Theorem text*

i.e. the "Theorem" string is both boldface and italics. When I remove the star in \spnewtheorem, and define instead

`\spnewtheorem{theorem*}{Theorem}{\bfseries}{\itshape}`

I obtain

**Theorem 1** *Theorem text*

as expected. I think this may be a bug in the definition of \spnewtheorem*. How does one correct it or notify it to Springer? Does anyone know?

My svjour3.cls file is dated "2010/11/25 v3.3" and my pdflatex executable is version
"pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Homebrew)"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

> How does one correct it?

I suggest you write

```
\spnewtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}{\upshape\bfseries}{\itshape}
```

i.e., add the directive `\upshape`.

Of course, you may also choose to contact Springer and alert them to an issue that may be a bug.

[image]

---

*Addendum*, prompted by @egreg's comment: Just in case your document  happens to modify the default font family and/or font encoding, it would be preferable to execute

```
\spnewtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\itshape}
```

i.e., to replace `\upshape` (used in the earlier instruction) with `\normalfont`. Of course, do make sure to execute `\normalfont` *before* rather than after `\bfseries`.

```
\documentclass{svjour3}
\spnewtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\itshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem*} Theorem text \end{theorem*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `\normalfont` instead of `\upshape`.

Comment: Thanks for these answers!